# Calculate the square root of the sum of the squares of the prime factors of an input number

Tags: optimization, c

This question is related to another one that I have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1091143/131263).

I need to find ways to improve the runtime performance of the following piece of C-code.

I want to increase `RANGE` to around 1G, and still complete the execution within a reasonable time.

---

**Auxiliary data structures:**

```
#define RANGE 16000000

uint08 sieve[RANGE]    = {0};
uint32 prime[RANGE/16] = {0}; // only around RANGE/log(RANGE) are primes
uint32 numOfPrimes     =  0 ;
```

**Initialize the auxiliary data structures:**

```
void CalcAuxiliaryData()
{
    uint32 i,j;

    uint32 root = (uint32)sqrt((double)RANGE);

    for (i=2; i<=root; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == 0)
            for (j=i+i; j<RANGE; j+=i)
                sieve[j] = 1;
    }

    for (i=2; i<RANGE; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == 0)
            prime[numOfPrimes++] = i;
    }
}
```

**Calculate the square root of the sum of the squares of the prime factors of an input number:**

```
uint32 CalcDiagonalLen(uint32 n)
{
    uint32 i;

    uint64 square;
    uint32 length;

    if (sieve[n] == 0) // quickly resolve the case of a prime number
        return n;

    square = 0;
    for (i=0; i<numOfPrimes && n>1; i++)
    {
        uint32 p = prime[i];
        uint64 pp = (uint64)p*p;
        while (n%p == 0)
        {
            n /= p;
            square += pp;
        }
    }

    length = (uint32)sqrt((double)square);
    if ((uint64)length*length == square)
        return length;

    return 0; // indicate that the result is not integer
}
```

**Calculate the square root of the sum of the squares of the prime factors of each number:**

```
int main()
{
    uint32 i;

    uint32 diagonal_len;

    CalcAuxiliaryData();

    for (i=2; i<RANGE; i++)
    {
        diagonal_len = CalcDiagonalLen(i);
        if (diagonal_len != 0)
            printf("%u %u\n",i,diagonal_len);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Function `CalcDiagonalLen` holds the bottleneck, but any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @MOehm's [second answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/75737/34177), I have managed to increase `RANGE` to 4 billion:

**Sieve Interface:**

```
#include <limits.h>

// Defined by the user (must be less than 'UINT_MAX')
#define RANGE 4000000000

// The actual length required for the prime-sieve array
#define ARR_LEN (((RANGE-1)/(3*CHAR_BIT)+1))

// Assumes that all entries in 'sieve' are initialized to zero
void Init(char sieve[ARR_LEN]);

// Assumes that 'Init(sieve)' has been called and that '1 < n < RANGE'
int IsPrime(char sieve[ARR_LEN],unsigned int n);

#if RANGE >= UINT_MAX
    #error RANGE exceeds the limit
#endif
```

**Sieve Implementation:**

```
#include <math.h>

#define GET_BIT(sieve,n) ((sieve[(n)/(3*CHAR_BIT)]>>((n)%(3*CHAR_BIT)/3))&1)
#define SET_BIT(sieve,n) sieve[(n)/(3*CHAR_BIT)] |= 1<<((n)%(3*CHAR_BIT)/3)

static void InitOne(char sieve[ARR_LEN],int d)
{
    unsigned int i,j;
    unsigned int root = (unsigned int)sqrt((double)RANGE);

    for (i=6+d; i<=root; i+=6)
    {
        if (GET_BIT(sieve,i) == 0)
        {
            for (j=6*i; j<RANGE; j+=6*i)
            {
                SET_BIT(sieve,j-i);
                SET_BIT(sieve,j+i);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Init(char sieve[ARR_LEN])
{
    InitOne(sieve,-1);
    InitOne(sieve,+1);
}

int IsPrime(char sieve[ARR_LEN],unsigned int n)
{
    return n == 2 || n == 3 || (n%2 != 0 && n%3 != 0 && GET_BIT(sieve,n) == 0);
}
```

**MOehm's Algorithm:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_HIT_COUNT (RANGE/20) /* change the division factor if necessary */

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned int x;
}
hit;

char sieve[ARR_LEN]     = {0};
hit hits[MAX_HIT_COUNT] = {0};
unsigned int hit_count  =  0;

void Sprawl(unsigned long long n,unsigned long long sum,unsigned long long p)
{
    unsigned long long x = (unsigned long long)sqrt((double)sum);
    if (x*x == sum)
    {
        if (hit_count >= MAX_HIT_COUNT)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Hits overflow\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        hits[hit_count].n = (unsigned int)n;
        hits[hit_count].x = (unsigned int)x;
        hit_count++;
    }

    while (p < RANGE)
    {
        if (IsPrime(sieve,(unsigned int)p))
        {
            if (n*p >= RANGE)
                break;
            Sprawl(n*p,sum+p*p,p);
        }
        p++;
    }
}
```

**Test Case:**

```
int hitscmp(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    const hit* aa = (const hit*)a;
    const hit* bb = (const hit*)b;
    return (aa->n > bb->n) - (aa->n < bb->n);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i;

    Init(sieve);

    Sprawl(1,0,2);

    qsort(hits,hit_count,sizeof(*hits),hitscmp);

    for (i=0; i<hit_count; i++)
        printf("%12u%12u\n",hits[i].n,hits[i].x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sieve approach to create an array of square sums. For any new prime that you sieve, you have:

```
sqsum[m * p] = sqsum[m] + p*p;
```

You can build that array as you go. The primes need a square sum value, too.

```
uint8_t sieve[RANGE] = {0};
uint64_t sqsum[RANGE] = {0};

void CalcAuxiliaryData()
{
    uint32_t i, j, k;

    for (i = 2; i <= RANGE; i++) {
        if (sieve[i] == 0) {
            uint64_t ii = (uint64_t) i * i;

            sqsum[i] = ii;

            j = 2; 
            k = i + i;
            while (k < RANGE) {
                sieve[k] = 1;
                sqsum[k] = sqsum[j++] + ii;
                k += i;
            }
        }
    }
}

uint32_t CalcDiagonalLen(uint32_t n)
{
    uint64_t square;
    uint32_t length;

    if (sieve[n] == 0) return n;

    square = sqsum[n];
    length = sqrt(square);
    if ((uint64_t) length * length == square) return length;

    return 0;
}
```

This approach adds more time to the initialisation, because you can't cut sieving short at `sqrt(RANGE)`, but the sum lookup is fast.

You could also create a lookup array that tells you whether a number is a perfect square or not, but the `sqrt` function isn't the bottleneck here. And you could make the array itself a direct lookup table for the diagonal length.

Comment: Are you sure that it takes non-unique factors into consideration as well? For example, `12 = 2*2*3`, so it needs to calculate `4+4+9` and not just `4+9`.

Comment: In addition, the `uint64_t sqsum[RANGE]` array will make it impossible in terms of memory usage, as the size of the arrays is now twice as large as the original `uint32_t prime[RANGE]` array.

Comment: Nevertheless, I like the idea, and I'll see what I can do with it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've tested my approach and compared it with your solution. I acknowledge that the array is big, but you can always allocate it on the heap, chunk-wise if need be, so that `sqsum[n]` maps to `sqsum[n/S][n%S]` where `S` is the chunk size.

Comment: Hmmm. I've played a bit with this and memory will be an issue, even when you chunk it. A segmented implementation does not seem to work here, because you have to keep sums for all numbers.

Answer (score 3):

As I've seen that my seemingly clever answer runs into serious memory problems sooner or later, I'll post a second answer that promotes a memory efficient, but fast bottom-up approach that basically only requires storage for the sieve of Erathostenes. (I've kept the original representation of one byte per number, but that can be easily compressed by a factor of 16 by using bit arrays and by not storing even numbers.)

Instead of doing the factorisation for each number and enumerating the numbers sequentially, we can vitsit all numbers in another fashion and keep track of our square sums.

We start with a number of 1, a sum of zero and with the first prime, 2. Then we spread out the solution recursively from this point by either going up, which means we consider the number, which is the current number multiplied by the current prime:

```
n, sum, p -> n*p, sum + p*p, p
```

Or by going right, which means that we advance the prime number to the next prime (without any evaluation):

```
n, sum, p -> n, sum, next(p)
```

The sum of squares is calculated as we go. When `n` exceeds the ceiling `RANGE`, recursion stops.

The drawback to this solution is that the numbers are vistied out of order. The first draft code below just printed the hits. The sorting (and assesment of the conjecture) had to be done with an external program.

I've now updated the code so that it keeps a linear, fixed-size array that is later sorted by increasing values of `n`. That array is checked for overflows. When an overflow occurs, the heuristics `RANGE / 1000` must be corrected. The entiries to `struct hits` are 64-bit ints, which is wasteful for the current `RANGE`.

As the `RANGE` increases, it might be worth keeping a red-bleck tree or something similar of the hits, which doesn't require a huge contiguous chunk of memory. A red-black tree would already store the items in a sorted way.

Anyway, here's my new proposal:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



#define RANGE 16000000u
#define NHITS (RANGE / 1000)

uint8_t sieve[RANGE] = {0};

struct hit {
    uint64_t n;
    uint64_t l;
};

struct hit hits[NHITS];
size_t nhits = 0;

void init(void)
{
    uint32_t i, k;

    for (i = 2; i*i < RANGE; i++) {
        if (sieve[i] == 0) {
            for (k = i + i; k < RANGE; k += i) sieve[k] = 1;
        }
    }
}

int64_t perfect(uint64_t sq)
{
    uint64_t l = sqrt(sq);
    if (l * l == sq) return l;

    return 0u;
}

int sprawl(uint64_t n, uint64_t sum, uint64_t p)
{
    uint64_t l;

    if (n >= RANGE) return 0;

    l = perfect(sum);
    if (l) {
        if (nhits >= NHITS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Hits overflow\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        hits[nhits].n = n;
        hits[nhits].l = l;
        nhits++;
    }

    while (p < RANGE) {
        if (sieve[p] == 0) {
            uint64_t nn = n*p;

            if (nn >= RANGE) break;
            sprawl(nn, sum + p*p, p);
        }
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int hitscmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct hit *aa = a;
    const struct hit *bb = b;

    return (aa->n > bb->n) - (aa->n < bb->n);
}

int main()
{
    size_t i;

    init();
    sprawl(1, 0, 2);

    qsort(hits, nhits, sizeof(*hits), hitscmp);

    for (i = 0; i < nhits; i++) {
        printf("%16llu%16llu\n", hits[i].n, hits[i].l);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That code still processes 16,000,000 numbers in less than 2s and 160,000,000 in less than 20s - sorting doesn't seem to take much of the overall time.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'll give it a try Thank you very much for your effort on this one. BTW, should be `"%llu"` there. Also, any reason why function `perfect` returns a signed `int64_t`?

Comment: Yeah, `u` for unsigned of course. Shouldn't matter for now. Using `int64_t` throughout saves me worrying about cut-offs when I'm doing 32-bit arithmetic. I prefer that to your approach to cast in the expression proper, but each to their own, I think.

Comment: Wow, very nice!!! One thing I'll need to sort out though, is getting those numbers printed in sorted order, since I am essentially looking for sequences of 4 consecutive numbers that yield 4 integer square roots (see the [original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091143/prime-factorizations-that-yield-hyperrectangles-with-integer-diagonals), as mentioned at the beginning of my post). Any idea how to get that done in your current implementation?

Comment: I've edited the code so that it keeps a list of hits that are sorted later and then printed in order.

Comment: Well, I gotta admit that when I published this question, I expected a couple of minor improvement suggestions at most. I just tried your code with `#define RANGE (1<<30)` (i.e., 1G), and it completed within less than a minute (compiled with optimization enabled). I have not gone over the values to make sure that it doesn't miss anything (I mean, I did, but just for a small range of 500 or so). Other than that, very impressive. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I have to take it back. You've got some serious bug in the code above. I have not investigated it, but the output is missing many results, which have mislead me thinking I was seeing every result in front of me. As a simple example, change `RANGE` to 432000 (and also get rid of that `/1000`, in order to make it work). Now, when you run the program, the last printed number is 431802, where clearly 431801 and 431803 (both of which are prime) are missing. Can you please review your answer?

Comment: The algorithm is sound, I think, but the implementation has a bug: `p` should be 64 bits wide, otherwise `p*p` overflows at around 2^16. This problem will arise again when you try to go beyond 4G. I've updated the code.

Comment: OK, thanks. This code does not allow me to test beyond 500 Million, and even for that, I get "Hits overflow". If I adjust the `RANGE/1000` heuristics, then I run out of memory. However, the memory consumption itself can be significantly reduced. Both fields in `struct hit` can be 32-bit each, because `RANGE > n >= l`. And since `RANGE` is 32 bits at most, so will `n` and `l` be. You then need to change `l*l == sq` to `(uint64_t)l*l == sq`, change function `perfect` to return a `uint32_t`, and change `hits[nhits].n = n` to `hits[nhits].n = (uint32_t)n`.

Comment: With the changes mentioned in the previous comment, I was able to define `RANGE` as `1200000000`, define `NHITS` as `(RANGE/15)` and run the program to completion. It will be good if you can update your answer according to this (as well as according to changes mentioned in the previous comment).

Comment: I'm not your contractor, you know. I'm a bit loth to update the code. I've provided you with an algorithmic means to tackle your problem, but it is still your problem.

Comment: Suit yourself. I just wanted to accept the answer!